# Edit got rejected after I approved it and then edited post

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, revisions-list

So I approved [an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31438). Then I went to the question revs, clicked to edit the last rev and edited it. Suggested edit got rejected.

I think that edit should be autoapproved when I submit an edit to the post I already approved an edit on.

Or just don't allow to edit if you already reviewed an edit and it stills need someone's review.

Comment: Did you hit "edit" on the post, or did you edit from the revisions page?

Comment: @Anna from the revs.

Comment: The actual bug is that you should not be able to edit the post when it still got a pending suggested edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not approve the edit. You only **voted** to approve. The edit was still just pending. By then editing the post from the revisions page, you triggered an auto-reject from Community (which has a veto vote), as the suggested-edit-under-review could no longer be applied.

This is *by design*; if an edit is applied to a post all pending suggested edits are rejected as the revision from which they were based no longer exists. By going to the revision list to edit a revision you are *explictly bypassing* the suggested edit.

You should instead have picked *Approve and Edit*. In that case Community will auto-approve the edit (again with a binding vote) and your new edit is applied on top of that edit.

Since that system is *already in place*, I see no reason for the current behaviour to change.  It could be argued that the explicit revision edit is a deliberate mechanism to bypass suggested edits, and auto-approving just because you voted would be very surprising indeed.

Comment: I know. My question is more like request.

Comment: @nicael: yet you tagged it 'bug'.

Comment: @nicael If you felt the compelling need to go edit the post from an earlier revision that's a *very* strong sign that the editor was doing something wrong.  If we did want to do something automatically in these cases it would almost certainly be to reject the edit.

Comment: Normal edit is not possible so I do agree that being able to edit is a bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I am 90% certain that being able to edit from the revision page is by design. It also lets you edit older revisions and promote those to the new revision, so it is gives you a general 'override' option.